# My Toshiba Laptop won't boot up

Tags: boot, windows-10

So this is a long story, but my laptop that was running Windows 10 crashed about a month ago and when I tried restarting my laptop, it got caught in a boot loop.

To get out of the boot loop, I went into safe mode and tried to type the password, but nothing would happen. My keyboard was fine, so I tried to reset my laptop completely. I wiped the hard drive half way, but then it stopped and said an error occurred to I went to try it again with the F-function and it went halfway again and said an error occurred.

So with the F-function I went into advanced options then I saw an option that said 'Maintain your PC' so I clicked on it and it told me that it would wipe the whole hard drive so I clicked OK then it started. Once it finished my laptop restarted.

When I booted it up the Toshiba logo would pop up but then went black and for 2 seconds some text was in the top left corner and it said

> 'Insert system disk in drive. Press any key when ready....'

Then it went back to the Toshiba logo and did the whole thing again. I used the function key <kbd>F10</kbd> and then some more text came saying:

> 'Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to enter INTEL(R) setup'

So I pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> simultaneously. Then this screen pops up and at the top it says:

> 'Intel (R) Management Engine BIOS Extension v9.0.0.0025/Intel(R) ME v9.5.30.1808 Copyright(C) 2003-13 Intel Corporation. All Rights Reserved'

There are four options:

- MEBx Login
- Intel(R) ME General Settings
- Intel(R) AMT Configuration
- MEBx Exit.

Intel(R) ME General Settings and Intel(R) AMT Configuration are not selectable. When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on MEBx Login a blue tab pops up and says:

> 'Intel(R) ME Password.'

I know the password is `ADMIN` so I type that in then a new text pops up and says:

> 'Intel(R) ME New Password.'

I type in `admin` again then it says Verify Password so I type in `admin`. Then it says MEBx Login Error Error applying new password and now every time I boot up my laptop the text with the 'Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>' pops up and I cannot use the function keys anymore.

Comment: Do you know that's very, very hard to read?  http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paragraph  You'll get a lot more help if your posting is understandable.

Comment: Please provide proper details, so that we can help you in the best possible way. Include the following in your question - - Error messages encountered. - Sources of solutions followed - Specification of the laptop, etc.

Comment: I suspect there are multiple issues here and that the SuperUser Q&A format might not be the best way for you to get the help you need. If the laptop is still under warranty I would take it back to the retailer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you might just want to reinstall Windows 10 from scratch. Put the install disk into your PC when it is on, then do a hard shutdown and boot from the disk. I don't think the Intel setup panel is really going to help you there.

If you don't have a Windows 10 install disk, you can follow [these instructions](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-create-windows-10-installation-disk-or-bootable-usb/) to create one.